# Web crawling: python saving file with -o file.json as utf-8: the output shows characters like \u00a9

Tags: python, json, utf-8, scrapy, web-crawler

Using scrapy crawler I am trying to extract data from html page and save the output as json file using command line:

```
scrapy crawl Product -o test.json
```

in my code I am using

```
for desc in response.css('div.pdp__description').extract():
            yield {
                'desc' : desc
            }
```

but it saves the data using \u00a0 and similar characters,
what should I do?

Comment: \u00a0 is a non-break space in unicode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: it shows a lot of characters like  \u00a9, \u0130, and not only this, thanks

Comment: Your encoding should be in utf. If you want ascii then use `unicodedata.normalize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'` in your `settings.py`.

Refer to the documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING#feed-export-encoding